# Create proxyserver and access the remote application webpage

Tags: c#, .net, proxy

Someone could you please guide me that how can I create a proxy server in mvc application and access the remote applications (webpage) through the proxy url. Meanwhile I have to intercept the webpage to modify the style of it. Thanks in advance.